# How to filter one model based on multiple models in flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have three tables, User, Post, and Likes.My like and unlike posts are working so far but now I want to return the list of users that liked a particular post.The Likes holds the user_id and post_id as foreign keys and is populated once the user likes or dislikes post.Now I want to filter all the users that liked a particular post but only the first post like user is being returned and three users already like that post.

Please see code below:

Use model

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
username = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True, unique = True)
password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
liked = db.relationship(
  'Likes',
  foreign_keys = 'Likes.user_id',
  backref = 'user', lazy = 'dynamic')

def like_post(self, post):
if not self.has_liked_post(post):
like = Likes(user_id = self.id, post_id = post.id)
db.session.add(like)

def unlike_post(self, post):
if self.has_liked_post(post):
  Likes.query.filter_by(
    user_id = self.id,
    post_id = post.id).delete()

def has_liked_post(self, post):
return Likes.query.filter(
  Likes.user_id == self.id,
  Likes.post_id == post.id).count() > 0
```

Post model

```
class Meetup(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
body = db.Column(db.String(120))
timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index = True, default=datetime.utcnow)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
likes = db.relationship('MeetupLike', backref = 'meetup', lazy = 'dynamic')
```

Likes model

```
class Likes(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
```

Route

```
@app.route('/applicants/<int:post_id>')
def get_users(post_id):
likes = Likes.query.filter_by(post_id = post_id).first_or_404()
users = User.query.filter(User.id == likes.user_id).all()
return render_template('likes.html', title = "Users", users = users)
```

template

```
<table>
  {% for user in users %}
  <tr valign="top" >
    <td>
    {{ user.firstname }}
   </td>
  < /tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I already have a post with three likes and want to return all three user details but only one is returning.

Answer (score 0):

In here you are getting the first Like and not all Likes

```
likes = Likes.query.filter_by(post_id = post_id).first_or_404()
```

Instead you should be getting all of them and passing the list:

```
likes = Likes.query.with_entities(Likes.user_id).filter_by(post_id = post_id).all()
users = User.query.filter(User.id.in_(likes)).all()
```

You can also try using a JOIN.

Comment: how do I use join in this case? I'm getting error `Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type`